# Can we set only one side shadow of View in React Native?

Tags: react-native, shadow

As the title saying, how can we set only one side shadow of View in React Native, or hide any side shadow? 
What I want is showing the only one side shadow, any solutions?

Answer (score 14):

Use this

```js
const style = {
  shadowColor: "#000000",
  shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 }, // change this for more shadow
  shadowOpacity: 0.4,
  shadowRadius: 6,
}
```

For example:

1. `shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 10 }` shadows place only in bottom of View
2. `shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: -10 }` shadows place only in top of View
3. `shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 0 }` shadows place only in right of View
4. `shadowOffset: { width: -10, height: 10 }` shadows place only in left of View

Comment: In android try your to shadow its not working

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it by two ways:

1.Using [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) Plugin:

```
<LinearGradient start={{ x: 1, y: 0 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }} colors={['#e4e2e4', '#FFF']} style={{height:8}} ></LinearGradient>
```

2.Without using Plugin:

```
<View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'#e9e8e9'}} ></View>
<View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'#e4e2e4'}} ></View>
<View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'#efeeef'}} ></View>
<View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5'}} ></View>
<View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'#fafafa'}} ></View>
<View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'#fdfdfd'}} ></View>
<View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'#fefefe'}} ></View>
<View style={{height:1,backgroundColor:'#fff'}} ></View>
```

Comment: I did the same, using LinearGradient. It works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can make your shadow of your own view using like this code:

```
<View style={{borderTopColor:'#ebebeb',borderTopWidth:1,borderBottomWidth:5,borderRightWidth:2,borderLeftWidth:2,borderColor:'#bcbaba',}}>

</View>
```

This help me pls use this according your use..

Comment: I have tried your code, actually it doesn't like the real shadow at all, especially when the width is full of screen.