# how to removing Top shadow of material-top-tabs?

Tags: css, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

**Current Behavior**

- Top side of tabBar has shadow.

[image]

**Expected Behavior**

- how to remove top shadow of top tabBar?
- tried elevation: 0 but it also removes bottom shadow.
- **Side note** - How top shadow was achieved for Tabs.Navigator (react navigation)? as box-shadow properties does not work for android and elevation only shows shadow to bottom.

**How to reproduce**

```
<>
<Header /> //App name custom component
<Tabs.Navigator
        ...
        tabBarOptions={{
          ....
          style: {
            // elevation: 0, 
          },
        }}>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```js
<>
<Header /> //App name custom component
<Tabs.Navigator
        ...
        tabBarOptions={{
          ....
          style: {
            elevation: 0,
            shadowColor: "#000000",
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 10 }, // change this for more shadow
            shadowOpacity: 0.4,
            shadowRadius: 6
          },
        }}>
```

`shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 10 }` shadows place only in bottom of View.
`shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: -10 }` shadows place only in top of View.
`shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 0 }` shadows place only in right of View.
`shadowOffset: { width: -10, height: 10 }` shadows place only in left of View.

Found this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505771/can-we-set-only-one-side-shadow-of-view-in-react-native).